# How to get a string in applescript that contains a quote

Tags: applescript

I want to have a string that contains a quote. So the code would look something like this: `return "hello"world"` and it should return `hello"world`. In other programming languages you could either escape the quote or use the other quote, but neither seems to work in Applescript.

Comment: Did you try `"hello\"world"`?

Comment: It comes with the \

Comment: @user3439894 Write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test these two lines of *code*:

```
set foo to "Hello\"World"
display alert foo
```

You'll see the real value of `foo`, `Hello"World`, as apposed to `return foo` which shows: `"Hello\"World"`

You'll see the *double-quote* escaped in a `return` *statement* because what would normally receive `foo`, in this case, will strip the `\` from it.

[image]